# Need to write at specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

While writing data in csv, I want to write to a specific column like column 7 or column 12.
The Code that I have, writes only sequentially.

```
import csv

data = {}
data = ['sales','tax']


with open('test.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
   a = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
   a.writerow(data)
```

Actual result :

```
coulmn 1 | coulmn 2 | coulmn 3 | coulmn 4 | coulmn 5
 Sale        Tax
```

Expected result :

```
coulmn 1 | coulmn 2 | coulmn 3 | coulmn 4 | coulmn 5
                                  Sale       Tax
```

Comment: The actual and expected result are the same..?

Comment: Why `data = {}` and then `data = ['sales','tax']` ? What should it be? Dict? List? What is `a`?  [mcve]? Including data?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an empty array and only populate the fields you want

```
data = [""] * 10
data[5] = "sales"
data[6] = "tax"

with open('test.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
   a = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
   a.writerow(data)
```